# X axis not moving right or left

Tags: unity, c#, camera

I've made a script that should have an x and a y axis, it goes up and down but not left or right; what am I doing wrong?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mouselook : MonoBehaviour
{


    public float mouseSensititvity = 100f;

    public Transform playerBody;


    float xRotation = 0f;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensititvity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensititvity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation = mouseX

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseY);

        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to GDSE! You should include your code in the question body instead of linking to some other website that contains the code.

Comment: I notice you're rotating playerBody around the up vector both times - is this intentional?

Comment: i dont really know, i was following a tutorial on this and he told me to do that so i did and it seemed to work for the y axis but not the x

Comment: nvm, i ened up fixing it

Comment: If you no longer need help with this issue, you can click the "delete" link at the bottom of the post to remove it, or post your solution as an Answer below to resolve the thread.